# ¿Por que me crea el objeto con 0 observaciones?

Tags: r

Buenas compañeros programadores. Estoy intentando crear un objeto para filtrar los outliers de un dataframe, pero al utilizar el comando filter del paquete tydiverse, me crea un objeto con 0 observaciones y todas mis variables. ¿Cual puede ser mi error?

```
outliersRAW <- filter(l00, kgsample == NA)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Gracias ahora si que he podido filtrar segun mis objetivos, ha sido de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1):

La comparación con un valor `NA` no se realiza con la función de igualdad, es fácil demostrarlo:

```
> NA == NA
[1] NA
```

Para comparar si un valor es `NA` se usa `is.na()`:

```
> is.na(NA)
[1] TRUE
```

En tu caso el filtro deberías implementarlo así:

```
utliersRAW <- filter(l00, is.na(kgsample))
```